# spring tool suite maven project adding libraries dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-tool-suite

I am about to give up on spring here; having come from .NET world and needing to learn java I was directed to spring as being the best environment to learn. I was given a sample project to work on with the class files and a whole bunch of dependencies. I created a maven project and then added the external jars in the configure build path. I added all the classes to my src/main/java/com/projectname folder. 
One of the build errors include not finding org.apache.jcs so I figured I need to find this library externally. Looked online and found a dependency to add to my pom file.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache</groupId>
<artifactId>apache</artifactId>
<version>14</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I would assume that this would resolve any issues but now I get the error:

```
Could not find artifact org.apache:apache:jar:14 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

I still do not understand how libraries are added in STS. In Visual Studio I will either download the library and point the reference to that library and all is fine or download using Nuget package manager. So am I still in fact missing this library or is there some other issue. Also I found a couple of tutorials to run a project but those are not helping me resolve this issues.

Any advice or direction to online sources will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I added the line below to my pom file but got a new error:

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing 
library 'C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\org\apache\http\jcs\1.3\jcs-1.3.jar'    
"Description Resource   Path    Location    
Type Missing artifact org.apache.http:jcs:jar:1.3   pom.xml /   
 line 29    Maven Dependency Problem "
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the below dependency in your maven pom xml, your maven in STS will try to download all the required dependencies you mentioned in your pom xml from the `central` repo.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so each associated library needs to be added to the pom. The one above does not download everything?Thanks for your response.

Comment: tried that but now getting another error - please see EDIT